# Cant Load Data which belongs to an Id in my Datatable

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, sequelize.js

I want to load only the `UserData` which belongs to the correct `AdminId`

In this Code you load all the `UserData`. It works fine

```js
async mounted() {
    this.userData = (await DataService.index()).data;
}
```

Now i want to give the `AdminId` to my backend. This is my Code which does not work.

```js
async mounted() {
    this.userData = (await DataService.index({ AdminId: this.$store.state.admin.id })).data;
}
```

This is my Backend: The Code works for where :`{AdminId: 1}`

```js
async index(req, res) {
    try {
        const { AdminId } = req.body
        const userData = await User.findAll({
            where: { AdminId: AdminId },
            include: [UserStatus,
                { model: SurveyResult, include: [Survey] }]

        })
            .map(user => user.toJSON())
    }
}
```

Comment: What is you question?

Comment: The Code do not work. If i try this:  (await DataService.index({ AdminId: this.$store.state.admin.id })).data; i dont get back any data.

but when i try this: (await DataService.index()).data; I git back the data.  I want all the data with the users who have the Adminid: this.$store.state.admin.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to req.query works

```
async index (req, res) {
try {
  const { adminId } = req.query
  const userData = await User.findAll({
    where: { AdminId: adminId },
    include: [UserStatus,
      { model: SurveyResult, include: [Survey] }]

  })
    .map(user => user.toJSON())

  res.send(userData)
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err)
}
```